# Interbase 2007 .net provider with Entity Framework support

Tags: entity-framework, interbase

I'd like to use Entity Framework for lazy loading and easy binding to controls.

I've tried to use IBProvider but it does not work for me. It's based on OleDb that's why I have got this exception:

> The store provider factory type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that implements this interface.

when I connected to Interbase with IBProvider with following connection string:

> add name="InterbaseEntities"
>   connectionString="metadata=res://*/db.csdl|db.Interbase.ssdl|res://*/db.msl;provider=System.Data.EntityClient;provider connection string="Provider=LCPI.IBProvider.3;Data Source=db.IBS;User ID=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Location=db.IBS""providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

OK. OleDbFactory really does not implement IServiceProvider interface.

Then I've tried to use FirebirdClient 3.0.2.0 and got exception "unsupported on-disk structure for file %path to file%;found 11.2,support 11.2".

OK. This is not Firebird database.

Does anyone know any solution to connect to interbase server and use it with Entity framework?